# Change img margin when text is wrapped

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, margin, stackpanel

I have a textblock and an image inside a stackpanel like this:

```
<StackPanel Height="Auto" Name=stackPanel" Width="Auto" Orientation="Horizontal" >
    <TextBlock Height="Auto" Name="textBlock" Width="Auto" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="168" />
    <Image Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="image" />
</StackPanel>
```

So the image is next to the textblock. If the text of textblock is to long, the text will be wrapped. Now I want the image to drop a row too, so the image stays next to the last word of the textblock.

My idea was to do this with an if-statement:

```
if (textblockBlock.ActualHeight > 35)
    {
        // change margin
    }
```

But this doesn't work, as the actual height of the textblock (appearently) doesn't change when the text is wrapped...

Could someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for text length, if length is greater than your specified value then change margin

```
if (textblock.Text.Length>40)
    { 
     //change margin
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question. Unless it's a fixed width font (which is unlikely), you can't make a reliable decision based on font width using the length of text. Further, there are multiple screen sizes, orientation, etc. to consider.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the image to always be at the "bottom" of the last row, just set the `VerticalAlignment` property to `Bottom`:

```
   <Image Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="image" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
```

This will cause the Image to always be aligned to the bottom, regardless of how many lines of text are used by the TextBlock.

Also, the `ActualHeight` property should be set, but depending on when you've attempted to read the value, it may not be available.

You could also use a `RichTextBox` (which on the Phone is actually read-only):

```
<RichTextBox MaxWidth="168" IsReadOnly="True">
    <Paragraph>
        <Run Text="This is the text from a question on Stack Overflow."/>
        <InlineUIContainer>
            <Image Source="Assets/circle.png" Width="20" Height="20" />                        
        </InlineUIContainer>
    </Paragraph>
 </RichTextBox>
```

With that, you can embed an `Image` directly in the content.